# How do i enable coloring in the line Using my Horizontal Timeline Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a horizontal bar, in which there is radio button. corresponding to each images. Leave the js part. i want that whenever the user click on the radio button a colour should cover the line upto that radio button. like
[image: Need this type]

color is provind in line span in css part with linear gradient but how i make it to enable. And which provide colour.

My code  -> https://codepen.io/mohit-04/pen/VwQdpXq
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    

    <div class="container">
      <div class="head">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="st st1 active">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593085512500-5d55148d6f0d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Y2FydG9vbnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt=""  checked
            />
            <p>Minions</p>
            <input type="radio"  class="profile" checked  name="fav_language" >
          </li>
          <li class="st st2">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637858868799-7f26a0640eb6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fGNhcnRvb258ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" 
              alt=""
            />
            <p>Happy</p>
            <input type="radio" class="setting" checked name="fav_language" >
          </li>
          <li class="st st3">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638803040283-7a5ffd48dad5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDF8fGNhcnRvb258ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt="" 
            />
            <p>Cartoon</p>
            <input type="radio" class="posts" name="fav_language">
          </li>
          <li class="st st4">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637855463319-9acb4e5aa44f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDl8fGNhcnRvb258ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt="" 
            />
            <p>Cat</p>
            <input type="radio" class="books"  name="fav_language" >
          </li>

          <li class="st st5">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578632767115-351597cf2477?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YW5pbWV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt=""
            />
            <p>anime</p>
            <input type="radio" class="extra" name="fav_language" >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="line">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <section class="minion-section">
          <span><i></i></span>
          <h1>Minion</h1>
          
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
            quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
            quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
            Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="happy-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Happy</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="cartoon-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Cartoon</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="cat-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Cat</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="anime-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Anime</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Epilogue:wght@200&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0 ;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-position: center;
    font-family: 'Epilogue', sans-serif;
}

img{
    width: 80px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 80vw;
}

ul.nav li .inner{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}

ul.nav li.active,
ul.nav li:hover{
    color: #444;
}

/* ul.nav li::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 7px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

} */


input {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

ul.nav li:hover::after,
ul.nav li.active::after{
    background: blue;
}

.line{
    width: 76%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #eee;
    height: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 11.5%;
    top: 41%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.line span {
    content: '';
    width: 2;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #282d35 0%, #282d35 100%);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    animation: anim .7s linear forwards;
    flex-direction: column;
}

section {
    /* padding-top: 400px; */
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 50px 25px 25px 125px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #282d35 0%, #282d35 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    /* padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px; */
    color: #fff;
}

section span {
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

section h1{
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

section p{
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    font-size: 18px;
}


.profile:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before

.setting:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.setting:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before

.posts:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.posts:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before
.posts:checked ~ .head .nav li.st3::before

.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before
.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st3::before
.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st4::before

.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st3::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st4::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st5::before{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}



.setting:checked ~ .head .line span{
    width: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read [linear-gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp). The syntax is as follow:

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);
```

direction could be diagonal also.
For e.g:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red, blue);
```

As provided your codepen, here's your snippet:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Epilogue:wght@200&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0 ;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-position: center;
    font-family: 'Epilogue', sans-serif;
}

img{
    width: 80px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 80vw;
}

ul.nav li .inner{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}

ul.nav li.active,
ul.nav li:hover{
    color: #444;
}

/* ul.nav li::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 7px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

} */


input {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

ul.nav li:hover::after,
ul.nav li.active::after{
    background: blue;
}

.line{
    width: 76%;
    margin: auto;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
    height: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 11.5%;
    top: 63%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.line span {
    content: '';
    width: 2;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #282d35 0%, #282d35 100%);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    animation: anim .7s linear forwards;
    flex-direction: column;
}

section {
    /* padding-top: 400px; */
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 50px 25px 25px 125px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #282d35 0%, #282d35 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    /* padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px; */
    color: #fff;
}

section span {
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

section h1{
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

section p{
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    font-size: 18px;
}


.profile:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before

.setting:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.setting:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before

.posts:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.posts:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before
.posts:checked ~ .head .nav li.st3::before

.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before
.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st3::before
.books:checked ~ .head .nav li.st4::before

.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st1::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st2::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st3::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st4::before
.extra:checked ~ .head .nav li.st5::before{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}



.setting:checked ~ .head .line span{
    width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    

    <div class="container">
      <div class="head">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="st st1 active">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593085512500-5d55148d6f0d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Y2FydG9vbnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt=""  checked
            />
            <p>Minions</p>
            <input type="radio"  class="profile" checked  name="fav_language" >
          </li>
          <li class="st st2">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637858868799-7f26a0640eb6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fGNhcnRvb258ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" 
              alt=""
            />
            <p>Happy</p>
            <input type="radio" class="setting" checked name="fav_language" >
          </li>
          <li class="st st3">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638803040283-7a5ffd48dad5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDF8fGNhcnRvb258ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt="" 
            />
            <p>Cartoon</p>
            <input type="radio" class="posts" name="fav_language">
          </li>
          <li class="st st4">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637855463319-9acb4e5aa44f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDl8fGNhcnRvb258ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt="" 
            />
            <p>Cat</p>
            <input type="radio" class="books"  name="fav_language" >
          </li>

          <li class="st st5">
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578632767115-351597cf2477?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YW5pbWV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
              alt=""
            />
            <p>anime</p>
            <input type="radio" class="extra" name="fav_language" >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="line">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <section class="minion-section">
          <span><i></i></span>
          <h1>Minion</h1>
          
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
            quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
            quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
            Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="happy-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Happy</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="cartoon-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Cartoon</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="cat-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Cat</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="anime-section">
            <span><i></i></span>
            <h1>Anime</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
              quaerat quos eligendi distinctio velit. Id, a, amet, similique saepe
              quaerat quam veniam suscipit exercitationem ut quidem odio?
              Necessitatibus, velit recusandae.
            </p>
          </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```